# What plugins do I need enabled to run a Fullnode?

Tags: nodeos

I'd like to run a fullnode with all blocks and transaction history so that I can access this data using the API, and I can't seem to find any definitive documentation on this.

My config:

```
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::history_api_plugin

curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_info
{"server_version":"1e9ca55c","chain_id":"cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f","head_block_num":5551,"last_irreversible_block_num":5550,"last_irreversible_block_id":"000015ae89478fba8bab59f621edb1a2c479e0e2c422dcfa2910245ab5dc93eb","head_block_id":"000015af76513509114cc457ef883d12ca14c4216df15a09aafd0c21f17e3375","head_block_time":"2018-10-11T02:59:01.500","head_block_producer":"eosio","virtual_block_cpu_limit":51461454,"virtual_block_net_limit":270355945,"block_cpu_limit":199900,"block_net_limit":1048576,"server_version_string":"v1.3.2"}
```

Output from fullnode (disk space used barely increasing):

```
2018-10-11T03:42:24.000 thread-0   producer_plugin.cpp:1419      produce_block        ] Produced block 00002a0433e1db38... #10756 @ 2018-10-11T03:42:24.000 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 10755, confirmed: 0]
2018-10-11T03:42:24.501 thread-0   producer_plugin.cpp:1419      produce_block        ] Produced block 00002a059326cb08... #10757 @ 2018-10-11T03:42:24.500 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 10756, confirmed: 0]
2018-10-11T03:42:25.005 thread-0   producer_plugin.cpp:1419      produce_block        ] Produced block 00002a06a4460513... #10758 @ 2018-10-11T03:42:25.000 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 10757, confirmed: 0]
2018-10-11T03:42:25.501 thread-0   producer_plugin.cpp:1419      produce_block        ] Produced block 00002a07cf26f954... #10759 @ 2018-10-11T03:42:25.500 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 10758, confirmed: 0]
2018-10-11T03:42:26.000 thread-0   producer_plugin.cpp:1419      produce_block        ] Produced block 00002a08be321f4f... #10760 @ 2018-10-11T03:42:26.000 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 10759, confirmed: 0]
2018-10-11T03:42:26.501 thread-0   producer_plugin.cpp:1419      produce_block        ] Produced block 00002a09eef90251... #10761 @ 2018-10-11T03:42:26.500 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 10760, confirmed: 0]
2018-10-11T03:42:27.000 thread-0   producer_plugin.cpp:1419      produce_block        ] Produced block 00002a0ac5b68ca3... #10762 @ 2018-10-11T03:42:27.000 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 10761, confirmed: 0]
2018-10-11T03:42:27.500 thread-0   producer_plugin.cpp:1419      produce_block        ] Produced block 00002a0b1404252e... #10763 @ 2018-10-11T03:42:27.500 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 10762, confirmed: 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use pretty much the following:

```
--plugin eosio::wallet_api_plugin 
--plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin 
--plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --filter-on "*"
```

Please note that `--filter-on "*"` is applicable only if the `eosio::history_api_plugin` is set.

Comment: any idea how long it takes to sync? I only got about 100MB of blocks in 8 hours, which seems very slow

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to run also a producing node and if you want that your node can accept requests. So:

```
plugin = eosio::producer_plugin # if you want a producing node
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin # always required
plugin = eosio::http_plugin # to accept RPC API request
# plugin = eosio::history_api_plugin old name
plugin = eosio::mongo_db_plugin # new plugin replacing history api
```

To have more informations you can check [this article](https://steemit.com/eos/@greymass/consistency-in-configuration-of-public-eos-full-nodes) and the [official guide](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence) (even if it is related to a local testnet).